# Image compression with imagemin-contrib (Grunt)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I was wanting to test out the `imagemin-contrib` in `Grunt.js`.  I selected three `jpg` random images (sizes: 44kb, 92kb, 77kb, respectively) and set up the folder and plugin.

When I ran the `imagemin` grunt task, I received a message saying the photos were optimized successfully, but the numbers showed only a 5kb or 10kb reduction in size for the first two photos, and the third wasn't changed at all.

I was wondering if this was normal for an "optimized image"? I was expecting a more drastic drop in size. Could it be that the images I selected were simply already optimized? Or could it be in how I have written the grunt command?

Below is the code I used to execute the grunt command:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        //Image Min Plugin
        imagemin: {
            dynamic: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'photos/',
                    src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                    dest: 'photos/optim/'
                }]
            }
        }


    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['imagemin']);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General information**

Well that absolutely depends on the original state of these images. If they were already compressed (e. g. when exporting with photoshop) they can barely compressed further without having a loss in quality. So it's definetely possible that you won't profit a lot by the optimization. If these are uncompressed images however `grunt-contrib-imagemin` can help a lot.

The plugin does a great job for what it is supposed to do, but obviously it doesn't compress images if there's a loss in quality. Also it doesn't know if the image could be resized (which is often a very good compression). If you are looking for the best compression you could run pagespeed insights (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) which tells you if you can further losslessly compress the image **and** if you can optimize the images by uploading them in a different resolution. If you want/need more compression consider lossy compression, which can save lots of kbs with only a little loss of quality.

**The optimizationLevel option:**

Even though it won't affect the compression size much there is the `optimizationLevel` option which can be set to a level between 0 and 7. It enables a set of optimization operations and it is set to 3 by default. The higher you set the level the more computationally expensive the compression operation becomes (shouldn't matter anyways). So you can set it to 7 and see if how it affects the compression:

```
imagemin: {
            options: {
                optimizationLevel: 7
            }
            dynamic: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'photos/',
                    src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                    dest: 'photos/optim/'
                }]
            }
        }
```

> The optimization level 0 enables a set of optimization operations that
>   require minimal effort. There will be no changes to image attributes
>   like bit depth or color type, and no recompression of existing IDAT
>   datastreams. The optimization level 1 enables a single IDAT
>   compression trial. The trial chosen is what OptiPNG thinks it’s
>   probably the most effective. The optimization levels 2 and higher
>   enable multiple IDAT compression trials; the higher the level, the
>   more trials.

Reference: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin

Comment: This is the most amazingly complete answer I've ever received on here.  Thank you so much for taking the time to explain it fully.

Comment: I will add another piece of information because I actually forgot something

Comment: I think the optimizationLevel is only for .png, git says "optimizationLevel (png)"